# Group by error ssms, should be quick fix but can't find it

Tags: sql, ssms

Below is my query. I'm getting an error in the `group by` statement, and I cannot figure out why. I included the error as well.

```
SELECT a.[Order Date]
    ,a.[Customer #]
    ,a.[Order #]
    ,a.[Order Type]
    ,OrderTotal
    ,CASE 
        WHEN c.OfferType IN ('Catalog')
            THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
        END AS 'Catalog Match'
    ,b.ChannelGroup
FROM LWPIM.dbo.MarketingReporting a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sum([Total Price]) AS OrderTotal
    FROM LWPIM.dbo.MarketingReporting
    WHERE [Order Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01'
            AND '2016-06-30'
    GROUP BY [Order Date]
        ,[Total Price]
    ) d
LEFT JOIN User_Sandbox.dbo.OfferCodeOfferType c ON a.[Offer Number] = c.OfferCode
    AND a.[Matchback Offer Number] = c.OfferCode
LEFT JOIN User_Sandbox.dbo.GAData2016 b ON a.[Order #] = b.Order_Number
GROUP BY a.[Customer #]
    ,a.[Order #]
    ,a.[Order Date]
    ,a.[Order Type]
    ,OrderTotal
    ,CASE 
        WHEN c.OfferType IN ('Catalog')
            THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
        END
    ,b.ChannelGroup
ORDER BY a.[Order Date] DESC
    ,OrderTotal DESC
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

Comment: You are missing the **ON** clause from the **'d'** derived query.

Comment: And... are you sure you actually want to GROUP BY [Total Price] and SUM([Total Price])?? doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Thank you, that all helped, all comments appreciated.